# how to make dotplots with smoothed density fit in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am making this dotplot in ggplot2:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + geom_dotplot()
```

I want to show some sort of smoothed density fit to the observed dots on top of the dotplot. This does not look right:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + geom_dotplot() + geom_density()
```

I tried `stat_smooth()` but I get the error:

```
> ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg)) + geom_dotplot() + stat_smooth()
stat_bindot: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
Error: stat_smooth requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

thanks.

Comment: What doesn't look right? You realize that a density estimate isn't going to be on the same scale as binned counts, right?

Comment: @joran: exactly. that's why I want something that just fits a kernel density to the actual stacks of dots so that they are roughly on same scale

Comment: Actually, I think it _is_ just fitting an appropriate kernel density estimate, it's just that you don't like the result. To see what I mean, try using `geom_density(adjust = 0.5)`. There is no real "right" here, you will just have to tinker with the bin width and the kde parameters until you get something you find visually pleasing.

Comment: Look at the help page of `geom_violin()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smoothing formula in the `stat_smooth` function requires a `y` value, and since you have not specified one, you are seeing an error.

The error will go away if you specify a range of values for `y` e.g.:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = mpg)) + geom_dotplot() + stat_smooth()
```

**Edit**:

`stat_smooth()` works flawlessly with most other functions. An approximation of what you might want (with mpg on x and models on y) would be:

```
qplot(mpg, row.names(mtcars), data=mtcars, group=1, color=mpg, xlab="Miles Per Gallon", ylab="Model")  + stat_smooth()
```

Which would result in:

[image]

Comment: thanks. the code runs but it give an obviously wrong fit to the data

Comment: I am aware of that, I just wanted to demonstrate that stat_requires a y-range. Can you elaborate what you are trying to do? A quick qplot an be smoothed very nicely. I'll edit my answer to demo the function.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this myself (although I wanted to color my dots by group as well).  The issue is geom_dotplot ignores the y scaling and just stacks up dots based on the x-axis and how wide the dots are.  This means you set the y-axis yourself, and then tweak the plot's aspect ratio so the dots magically line up to the correct height.

Here is a utility function I wrote:

```
# Function to generate a normal curve
make.normal.density = function( a, mn=median(a), stdev=sd(a), numpts=500 ) {
  x.grid = seq(min(a), max(a), length= numpts)
  dens.all = dnorm(x.grid,mean=mn, sd = stdev)
  data.frame( x = x.grid, y = dens.all )
}


make.densodot.plot = function( X, group = NULL, binwidth, bw = binwidth, normal.density = FALSE ) {
  df = data.frame( X = X )
  if ( !is.null( group ) ) {
    df$group=group
  }

  # Hand-bin our dots
  scl = 1 / binwidth
  mn = round( scl * (min( X ) - binwidth/2 ) ) / scl
  breaks = seq( mn - binwidth/2, max( df$X + binwidth), by=binwidth )
  df = mutate( df, bin = cut( X, breaks=breaks ) )

  mx = max( table(df$bin ) )

  # Get density curve to plot
  if ( normal.density ) {
    dd = make.normal.density( df$X )
  } else {
    dens = density( df$X, bw=bw )
    dd = data.frame( x=dens$x, y=dens$y )
  }
  dmax = max( dd$y )

  # What fraction of density is in tallest histogram bar?
  frac = mx / nrow( df )

  # How high should density line be through the peak (to get relatively same area
  # under density curve (integrate curve over binwidth) vs. histogram bin (# dots in
  # the bin over total number of dots)
  ratio = (binwidth * dmax) / frac

  # Each unit of height is what in terms of dots? (The dots will stack up
  # without regard of y-axis, so we want to fix aspect ratio so the dots
  # correspond to the density line.)
  scaling = binwidth / ( (dmax / ratio) / (mx) )

  y.max = max( dmax, mx * binwidth/scaling )

  if ( is.null( group ) ) {
    plt = ggplot( df )+
      geom_dotplot( aes(x=X), method="histodot",
                    binwidth = binwidth, stackgroups = TRUE)
  } else {
    plt = ggplot( df )+
      geom_dotplot( aes(x=X, fill=group, col=group), method="histodot",
                    binwidth = binwidth, stackgroups = TRUE)
  }
  plt = plt +
    geom_line( data=dd, aes( x = x, y = y ) ) +
    coord_fixed(ratio = scaling, ylim=c(0, y.max ) ) +
    scale_y_continuous(name="", breaks=seq(0,by=binwidth/scaling, length.out=(mx+1)), labels=c(0:mx) )

  plt
}


make.densodot.plot( X = mtcars$mpg, binwidth=3 )
```